# How can I make the text stop moving when one DIV opens?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here's what I'm talking about: https://jsfiddle.net/npbfop3w/

**HTML**

```
<div id="ta35">

<!-- tab -->
<div>
  <div class="ta351">+</div>
  <div class="ta352">
    <div class="ta354">title</div>
    <div class="ta353">
      content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end -->

<!-- tab -->
<div>
  <div class="ta351">+</div>
  <div class="ta352">
    <div class="ta354">title</div>
    <div class="ta353">
      content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end -->

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#ta35{
  position:fixed;
  top:20px;
  left:20px
}

.ta351{
  text-align:center;
  line-height:20px;
  display:block;
  margin-top:10px;
  height:20px;
  width:20px;
  background: white;
  border:1px solid #eee;
  transition: ease 0.5s all;
  -o-transition: ease 0.5s all;
  -moz-transition: ease 0.5s all;
  -webkit-transition: ease 0.5s all
}
.ta351:hover{
  background:#ffb8cc
 }
.ta351.active{
  background:#ffb8cc;
}

.ta352:not(.active){
  display:none
}
.ta352{
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin-left:30px;
  top: -22px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  width:150px;
  text-align: justify;
  font-family: karla;
  font-size: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  color: #444
}

.ta353{
  padding:7px
}

.ta354{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: bold
}

#ta35 .cr00{
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0 7px 5px 0
}
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ta351").click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('active')){    $(this).removeClass('active');
        $(this).siblings('.ta352').slideUp(450);
    }else{
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(this).siblings('.ta352').slideDown(500);
        $(this).parents().siblings().children('.ta352').slideUp(450);
        $(this).parents().siblings().children('.ta351').removeClass('active');
    }
  });// thank you to scimonster @ stackoverflow for the help
});
```

My problem is that whenever I open the first tab, the `+` symbol on the second one moves down and I want it to stay still. I've tried using `inline-block` on `.ta351` but doing so makes the second tab's box have a weird jump effect or something: https://jsfiddle.net/5evusmgc/

So how can I make the `+` symbol stay in place and avoid that jumpy effect? Thank you so much for all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Another option:**

Clear the float and now the UI works fine I guess (both the `+` and `background` moving together)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".ta351").click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
      $(this).siblings('.ta352').slideUp(450);
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('active');
      $(this).siblings('.ta352').slideDown(500);
      $(this).parents().siblings().children('.ta352').slideUp(450);
      $(this).parents().siblings().children('.ta351').removeClass('active');
    }
  }); // thank you to scimonster @ stackoverflow for the help
});
```

```css
#ta35 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px
}

.ta351 {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  transition: ease 0.5s all;
  -o-transition: ease 0.5s all;
  -moz-transition: ease 0.5s all;
  -webkit-transition: ease 0.5s all
}

.ta351:hover {
  background: #ffb8cc
}

.ta351.active {
  background: #ffb8cc;
}

.ta352:not(.active) {
  display: none
}

.ta352 {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 30px;
  top: -22px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: justify;
  font-family: karla;
  font-size: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  color: #444
}

.ta353 {
  padding: 7px
}

.ta354 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: bold
}

#ta35 .cr00 {
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0 7px 5px 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ta35">

  <!-- tab -->
  <div>
    <div class="ta351">+</div>
    <div class="ta352">
      <div class="ta354">title</div>
      <div class="ta353">
        content
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- end -->

  <!-- tab -->
  <div>
    <div class="ta351">+</div>
    <div class="ta352">
      <div class="ta354">title</div>
      <div class="ta353">
        content
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- end -->

</div>
```

Comment: I didn't want the + and the background to move together but this fits better than the rest, so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are using slideUp effect, and applying duration, So it show like jumpy effect,

Please replace that duration to `0` and try.

You can see Jsfiddle demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vatsal18/5evusmgc/1/).

**EDITED**

Please Try below one

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vatsal18/5evusmgc/2/)

Comment: Unfortunately I really want that slide effect on the tabs. Isn't there a way to keep that effect and avoid the jumpy thing? Thank you for your suggestion though :)

Comment: Please Check Edited Answer, Its not showing jumping effect.